# How to send a request from Angular to http server to connect SignalR hub

Tags: c#, angular, signalr

I use the following code in order to connect to the hub on the server
My server is deployed in docker and it is HTTP not HTTPS
How do I get the client to connect to the hub?
Error:

> polyfills.e13fca6f3d31ac52.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myDomain.ru/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://myIp:5004/hub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = cathrasisraw-client-app;
  private hubConnectionBuilder!: HubConnection;
  offers: string[] = [];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.hubConnectionBuilder = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('http://serverIp:5004/hub',{
        skipNegotiation: false,
      })
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
      .build();
    this.hubConnectionBuilder
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started.......!'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while connect with server'));
    this.hubConnectionBuilder.on('SendMessageForUser', (result: any) => {
      this.offers.push(result);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Change this http://serverIp:5004/hub to https. Provide SSL on serverIp:5004/hub